# Tectonic latex - downloads/packages folder

Tags: pdftex, tectonic

I made a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/pull/690) for Tectonic. It works not as fast as I want: each run it tries to download the same packages again and again. I want to add volumes support to speed up build process.

I have to know what folder Tectonic uses for its' files, packages, etc.

I'm not able to find any documentations or settings about temporary directories.
Futhermore, if I run the docker image, and then - if I run `tectonic` inside the image, I will not find the downloaded files inside.

Can anyone point the way?

Answer (score 5):

Everything is stored in `$HOME/.cache/Tectonic`. (I used `strace` to figure it out.)

Comment: @modnar of course it does.  Did you read the actual question?  The OP is specifically asking "I have to know what folder Tectonic uses for its' files, packages, etc. I'm not able to find any documentations or settings about temporary directories." and the title of the question is "downloads/packages folder".  So I told them where Tectonic stores its files.  Not every question needs a two-pages answer.

Comment: Clément, my bad. You are absolutely right. I am deleting the first comment.

Comment: @modnar No worries :) Thanks.

Comment: Is this on Linux? I can't find a directory `$HOME/.cache/Tectonic` on Mac.

Comment: Correct, Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer. `~/.cache/Tectonic` is the cache path on Linux only. On MacOS, the path is `~/Library/Caches/Tectonic`. I don't know about Windows.

Source: http://tectonic.newton.cx/t/where-does-tectonic-put-support-files/79/2